# Formatting the output of this date range queries results

Tags: sql-server

The query below shows the first and last day of the next 3 quarters from a given date (the most recent in column `Time_Stamp`). I'm trying to change the output structure to show like the 2nd query.

Column `Time_Stamp`:

```
Time_Stamp
-----------
2014-06-04 16:01:14.000
2014-06-04 15:55:33.000
2014-06-04 15:45:05.000
```

New query

```
SELECT 
    --first day of next quarter
    DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, MAX(Time_Stamp)) + 1, 0) as StartDate,
    --last day of next quarter
    DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, MAX(Time_Stamp)) +2, 0)) as EndDate,
    --first day 2 quarters ahead
    DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, MAX(Time_Stamp)) + 2, 0) as StartDate,
    --last day, 2 quarters ahead
    DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, MAX(Time_Stamp)) +3, 0)) as EndDate,
    --first day 3 quarters ahead
    DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, MAX(Time_Stamp)) + 3, 0) as StartDate,
    --last day 3 quarters ahead
    DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, MAX(Time_Stamp)) +4, 0)) as EndDate
FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = 'Hospital1'
```

Outputs

```
StartDate               EndDate                 StartDate               EndDate                 StartDate               EndDate
----------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
2014-07-01 00:00:00.000 2014-09-30 00:00:00.000 2014-10-01 00:00:00.000 2014-12-31 00:00:00.000 2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 2015-03-31 00:00:00.000
```

2nd query which gives wrong dates but preferred format:

```
 WITH Start AS
 (
    SELECT 
        -- Returns first day of next quarter
        DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, MAX(Time_Stamp)) + 1, 0) as StartDate,
        -- Returns last day of next quarter
        DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, MAX(Time_Stamp)) +2, 0)) as EndDate
    FROM Survey
    WHERE MainHospital = 'Hospital1'    
),
Results AS
(
   SELECT StartDate, EndDate from Start
   UNION
   SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, EndDate), DATEADD(day, 91, EndDate) FROM Start
   UNION
   SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 92, EndDate), DATEADD(day, 182, EndDate) FROM Start
)
SELECT LEFT(StartDate,11) AS StartDate, LEFT(EndDate,11) AS EndDate FROM Results`
```

Preferred output format:

```
 StartDate   EndDate
----------- -----------
Jul  1 2014 Sep 30 2014
Oct  1 2014 Dec 30 2014
Dec 31 2014 Mar 31 2015
```

Comment: You've asked basically the same question about 3-4 times now, is this for a class and you don't understand the sql to get quarter dates start and end?  That was given to you several times.

Comment: I've also created the answer for myself each time Kevin Cook if you want to check. I've added a new answer again if you want to help and not troll.

Comment: These are completely different questions, I got the quarter dates on my own. This question that you've decided to troll does not ask for the quarter dates at. Only formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to tweak it a bit to fit your code but this should get you the date format you are looking for:

```
 SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), StartDate, 107) AS StartDate
```

I use this as a reference for datetimes, it's very helpful:
http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @TimeTable TABLE
( Time_Stamp DATETIME )

INSERT INTO @TimeTable
( Time_Stamp )
VALUES
('2011-06-04 16:01:14.000'),
('2014-06-04 16:01:14.000'),
('2014-06-04 15:55:33.000'),
('2014-06-04 15:45:05.000');    

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),DATEADD(QUARTER, n.number + 1, t.BeginYear)) as StartDate,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),DATEADD(SECOND, - 1, DATEADD(QUARTER, n.number + 2, t.BeginYear))) as EndDate
FROM
(
    select top 400 row_number() over(order by t1.number) as number
    from master..spt_values t1 
    cross join master..spt_values t2
) n
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, MIN(t.Time_Stamp)), 0) BeginYear, MAX(t.Time_Stamp) MaxDate FROM @TimeTable t
) t
WHERE DATEADD(QUARTER, n.number, t.BeginYear) < DATEADD(QUARTER, +2, t.MaxDate)
```

I create a numbers table that generates all the quarters values from the first date to 3 quarters after the last date as wanted in your business rules and then apply against your data to show the start and end dates.

I added an odd date in 2011 to show the overall flow so this will have more records than your example
Here is the output:

```
StartDate   EndDate
Jul  1 2011     Sep 30 2011 
Oct  1 2011     Dec 31 2011 
Jan  1 2012     Mar 31 2012 
Apr  1 2012     Jun 30 2012 
Jul  1 2012     Sep 30 2012 
Oct  1 2012     Dec 31 2012 
Jan  1 2013     Mar 31 2013 
Apr  1 2013     Jun 30 2013 
Jul  1 2013     Sep 30 2013 
Oct  1 2013     Dec 31 2013 
Jan  1 2014     Mar 31 2014 
Apr  1 2014     Jun 30 2014 
Jul  1 2014     Sep 30 2014 
Oct  1 2014     Dec 31 2014 
Jan  1 2015     Mar 31 2015
```

Comment: the master..spt_values is a system table, this part is just used to create a numbers table.

Comment: if you just want the last 3 records based off the max overall from your table, then just change DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, MIN(t.Time_Stamp)), 0) BeginYear from min to max.

Comment: Where would I set my original WHERE parameter FROM Survey?

Comment: in my example I created a temp table @TimeTable, just replace that with Survey in the outer apply from clause and add your where clause to pick the hospital. I created the temp so you could just cut and paste this into SSMS and run and see the query work easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1
  --first day of next quarter    
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, MAX(Time_Stamp)) + 1, 0)) as StartDate,
  --last day of next quarter
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, MAX(Time_Stamp)) +2, 0))) as EndDate,
  --first day 2 quarters ahead
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, MAX(Time_Stamp)) + 2, 0)) as StartDate,
  --last day, 2 quarters ahead
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, MAX(Time_Stamp)) +3, 0))) as EndDate,
  --first day 3 quarters ahead
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, MAX(Time_Stamp)) + 3, 0)) as StartDate,
  --last day 3 quarters ahead
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, MAX(Time_Stamp)) +4, 0))) as EndDate
 FROM Survey
 Where MainHospital = 'Hospital1'
 GROUP BY Time_Stamp
 ORDER BY Time_Stamp DESC
```

gets the date format but not in 2 columns

```
    StartDate    EndDate      StartDate    EndDate      StartDate    EndDate
------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------
Jul  1 2014  Sep 30 2014  Oct  1 2014  Dec 31 2014  Jan  1 2015  Mar 31 2015
```